# Retrieving data from unknown li with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have several chunks of code where I'm getting data from HTML that doesn't have very good structure for retrieving data, for example:

the items in the list where they might not always be in the same position... so I have to look at the data in `li > span` to see if I'm at the right spot.

```
  <div id="j-profile-header-details" class="vcard font-color-white">
    <h1 class="fn n font-color-white">User Name</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="font-color-meta-light">Title</span><a href="/foobar" class="url font-color-normal">User Title</a><span class="jive-orgchart-recenter font-color-meta"><a href="/foobar" class="font-color-meta-light" title="view in orgchart"><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-glyph-orgchart"></span></a>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="font-color-meta-light">Phone Number</span>+1(555) 5555555</li>
      <li><span class="font-color-meta-light">Email</span><a href="mailto:foo@bar.com" class="font-color-normal">foo@bar.com</a></li>
      <li><span class="font-color-meta-light">Manager</span>Bar, Foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I've tried a few different ways without luck, for example, to get the Title "User Title" these are the latest attempts:

```
  const headerDom = await profilePage.$(PROF_PAGE_HEADER_DETAILS_SELECTOR);
  let title = "";
  await profilePage.evaluate(() => {
    Array.from(headerDom.querySelectorAll('li')).some(li => {
      if (li.querySelector('span').textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "title") {
        title = li.querySelector('a').textContent.trim();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
  });
```

which gives me "headerDom is not defined".. if i bind it in.. it acts like the code within evaluate doesn't get ran at all (even a console.log at the top doesn't show), and

```
  const headerDom = await profilePage.$(PROF_PAGE_HEADER_DETAILS_SELECTOR);
  let title = "";
  (await headerDom.$$("li")).some(async li => {
    if ((await li.$eval('span', ele => ele.textContent)).trim().toLowerCase() === "title") {
      title = (await li.$eval('a.url', ele => ele.textContent)).trim();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

which (aside from being an `await`/`async` mess) is giving me `Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`, if I log out `li` in the first line of `some`... I get an ElementHandle object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a variable (`headerDom`) from the Node.js environment to your browser context and vice versa (`title`).

To do this, you need to pass it as argument like this:

```js
await page.evaluate(element => { ... }, elementHandle);
```

This would pass the element (handle) from your Node.js environment to your browser context. But I would not recommend to do that, better just pass your selector from your Node.js context to your script and then execute everything there.

Additionally, you cannot pass `title` back to your Node.js script like that. [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) will only pass the return value back to your script. The function is run in a different execution context (the browser).

Merging everything together, the code could look like this:

```js
  const title = await profilePage.evaluate((PROF_PAGE_HEADER_DETAILS_SELECTOR) => {
    let title = "";
    const headerDom = document.querySelector(PROF_PAGE_HEADER_DETAILS_SELECTOR);
    Array.from(headerDom.querySelectorAll('li')).some(li => {
      if (li.querySelector('span').textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "title") {
        title = li.querySelector('a').textContent.trim();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    return title;
  }, PROF_PAGE_HEADER_DETAILS_SELECTOR);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I just had to change `document.querySelectorAll` to `querySelector` and it is working for me now. (`querySelectorAll` returns a `nodeList` which does not have `Element` functions, so would fail at `headerDom.querySelectorAll`)